# Webflux + Netty NIO performance decrease ~30 times compared to traditional IO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux

We are having problems in network transfer while using Spring Boot 2.0, Webflux 5.0.7 and Netty 4.1.25. We want to transfer 100000 items serialized as JSON (roughly 10Mb of network traffic) to 1 client.

The performance of network transfer dramatically differ between NIO and traditional IO.
The test results are below:

```
Start reading 100000 from server in 5 iterations
Avg HTTP 283 ms
Avg stream 8130 ms
```

At the moment the number of **requests per second is not an issue**, but the network transfer speed is. We have read that in terms of network speed NIO may be about 30% slower but 1/30x is an overkill.

While sampling on client and serverside we have observed that the reason is mostly on the serverside implementation. From the screanshot below it is visible that most of the time server spends in methods `select()` and `doWrite()`.

[image: Sampling]

The endpoint code itself:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE})
@Validated
public class StreamingController {

    @GetMapping("/instruments/{eodDate}")
    public Flux<TestItem> getInstruments(
            @PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate eodDate,
            @RequestParam(required = false) Instant asOfTimestamp) {
        //Generate test data in memory
        List<TestItem> collect = IntStream.range(0, 100000)
             .mapToObj(i -> new TestItem.Builder().build())
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return Flux.fromIterable(collect);
    }
}
```

We are using Spring Boot configuration for Netty and we are suspecting that by default Netty is misconfigured.
We are looking for your help. I will add any other details by your request.

*Upd:*
The goal is to read whole response in batches to avoid putting all response into memory, because the expected data volumes are huge (couple of Gb). It is acceptable to consume batch of data on the client side instead of one element.

Comment: I don't understand.  What are you comparing that code with?  An in-memory `Stream`?  File I/O?  Raw socket I/O?

Comment: @StephenC On the client side I am hitting this endpoint first with regular REST HTTP and then with Webflux client and comparing the time needed to download the content. Spring handles difference in headers "application/json" vs "application/stream+json" and for HTTP call converts returned `Flux` to `Collection`. So I am basically I am comparing network speed.

Comment: Please elaborate - could you paste here more details about what you're comparing, the HTTP request/response headers you're making?

Comment: @BrianClozel I am comparing response time between 2 approaches in Swagger. To test REST HTTP I am sending  "application/json" header, to test Webflux I am sending  "application/stream+json". I inspect "Network" tab in browser to avoid time for Json deserialization.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not actually testing NIO vs. IO. Spring WebFlux applications are always using non-blocking IO at the server level (with Netty, Undertow, or any Servlet 3.1+ async IO compliant server).

In this case, you're comparing:

1. serving an `"application/json"` payload in one shot with Spring WebFlux
2. serving a stream `"application/stream+json"` response with Spring WebFlux

In the first case, Spring WebFlux is producing a response body in a reactive manner but leaves the buffering and the flushing decisions to the server itself. Writing to the network has a cost, a buffering a but and writing bigger chunks is efficient.

In the second case, you're asking Spring WebFlux to write and flush **for every element of the `Flux`**. This is useful when clients are listening to a (possibly infinite) stream of events and there might be some time between two different events. That approach consumes more resources and explains the performance difference.

So this benchmark is not showing IO vs. NIO, but streaming vs. non-streaming.

If you want fine-grained control over response writing/flushing, you can drop down to the level of `ServerHttpResponse` and use `writeAndFlushWith(Flux<Flux<DataBuffer>>)`, but this is quite low level since you're dealing with `DataBuffer` instances directly.

An alternative would be to create intermediate JSON objects that hold lists of `TestItem`, like:

```
public Flux<TestItemBatch> batch() {
    Flux<TestItem> items= //...;
    Flux<List<TestItem>> itemsLists = items.buffer(100);
    return itemsLists.map(list -> new TestItemBatch(list));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I agree this is probably the issue, could you suggest how can I configure Webflux or Netty to flush items in batches?

Comment: your client should request plain `"application/json"`, and it will write/flush normally

Comment: But what if I want to load the data in a streaming way and have Webflux as input on the client?

Comment: I don't understand. If you're loading data as a Flux, it's already loaded in a streaming way. The client on the other side of the HTTP connection doesn't matter here. If you want the server to flush for each element, then `"application/stream+json"` is the way to go.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't quire clear. I want to use `application/stream+json` but be able to flush data in batches to improve speed. Current situation is such that the producer (in memory) can feed items very fast and consumer has high speed of consumption so the bottleneck in current situation is the `flush` on each item. I've noticed your edit about `ServerHttpResponse`, could you please elaborate or provide a reference to the example?

Comment: We're entering a whole new territory here; so the client is expected to read groups of elements or the client is just waiting for the whole response? I don't have a sample with `writeAndFlushWith` as it's really low level and you'd be expected to deal with serialization and pooled resources manually.

Comment: the `"application/stream+json"` streaming contract in WebFlux flushes after each element and there's no contract for controlling the flushing behavior precisely AFAIK. I've improved my answer in case you're willing to consider a workaround: batching elements within JSON objects and flushing each one of those.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in our team we have also came up to similar solution. The goal is to read whole response in batches to avoid putting all response into memory, because the expected data volumes are huge (couple of Gb). It is acceptable to consume batch of data on the client side instead of one element.